# Finding confidence level

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation, confidence-interval

I am studying for my upcoming stats final exam and I come across this question:

Let X be a single observation from the uniform distribution:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
      0 & \text{otherwise} \\
      \frac{1}{\theta} &  0 ≤x ≤ \theta
\end{cases}$$

Suppose we use $(X, 1.5X)$ as a confidence interval for $\theta$. What is the
confidence level?

I have no idea how to start.  Since I am given a confidence interval, I believe I need to integrate the function from $X$ to $1.5X$, but I'm not sure what to do next, should I even integrate.  How can I solve this problem?

Comment: By definition, the confidence level is the probability $P_{\theta}(X\le \theta\le 1.5 X)$. So how can you use the distribution of $X$ to find this quantity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X$ follows a uniform distribution from $0$ to $\frac{1}{\theta}$.

For $X$ small enough, the interval does not include the parameter.

The interval includes the parameter from $1.5X=\theta$, which is equivalent to $X=\frac{2}{3}\theta$, up to $X=\theta$.

Can you compute the probability of having X in this range?

Comment: i think i get it now.  thanks!